# MUI autocomplete on array of object return one dimensional array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, mui-autocomplete

I have the following `Autocomplete` component:

```
    <Autocomplete
           options={channels}
           autoHighlight
           multiple
           disableCloseOnSelect
           value={form.channel_ids}
           getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
           onChange={(event, value) => updateForm({...form, channel_ids: value?.map(channel => channel.id)})}
           renderInput={params => 
                 <TextField
                     {...params}
                     label="Channels"
                     error={!!errors?.channel_ids}
                     helperText={errors?.channel_ids?.[0]}
                  />
             }
             isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value}
             renderOption={(props, option, {selected}) =>
                    <li {...props}>
                          <Checkbox
                             icon={<Icon path={mdiCheckboxBlankOutline} size={1} />}
                             checkedIcon={<Icon path={mdiCheckboxMarked} size={1} />}
                             style={{marginRight: 8}}
                             checked={selected}
                      />
    
                       {option.name}
                   </li>
             }
/>
```

The channels array:

```js
[
   {id: 1, name: 'Example 1'},
   {id: 2, name: 'Example 2'}
]
```

So far this is working fine:

- It shows the options with a checkbox;
- It checks the checkboxes;
- It renders the option label;

What isn't working is that it doesn't match the `value` and `options`. I want the Autocomplete to use an array of objects as options but to return a one dimensional array of selected ids. For example `[1]`, `[2]` or `[1, 2]`.

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short it's not possible to do it straight away. I read the component's documentation and it is not possible. What I can suggest to you, however, is to keep an external map to do the mapping ID-component in a work-around fashion.

```
const options = new Map(channels.map((channel) => ([channel.id, channel])))

// Since the option is mapped from the id the empty string will never be picked
const getOptionName = (option: string) => options.get(option)?.name ?? ''


<Autocomplete
           options={Array.from(options.keys())} // Modified
           autoHighlight
           multiple
           disableCloseOnSelect
           value={form.channel_ids}
           getOptionLabel={getOptionName} // Modified
           onChange={(event, value) => updateForm({...form, channel_ids: value})} // Modified
           renderInput={params => 
                 <TextField
                     {...params}
                     label="Channels"
                     error={!!errors?.channel_ids}
                     helperText={errors?.channel_ids?.[0]}
                  />
             }
             isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option === value}
             renderOption={(props, option, {selected}) =>
                    <li {...props}>
                          <Checkbox
                             icon={<Icon path={mdiCheckboxBlankOutline} size={1} />}
                             checkedIcon={<Icon path={mdiCheckboxMarked} size={1} />}
                             style={{marginRight: 8}}
                             checked={selected}
                      />
    
                       {getOptionName(option)} // Modified
                   </li>
             }
/>
```

Notice: if you think the computation of the map is too expensive in terms of time you can always use a memo.

```
const options = useMemo(() => new Map(channels.map((channel) => ([channel.id, channel]))),[channels])
```

Comment: This works, but needed to change the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to `isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => channels.get(option)?.id === value}`

Comment: Yeah, or directly `option === value` since we passed al the ids as options already